# Inline Assembly -- Access local char* variable -- gcc

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I am trying to write a simple program that prints out a C string without using one of the linux system calls or the standard C library functions. This is for learning purposes only, and I would never do this in production (unless I got really good at it =)).

First my system info:

```
[mehoggan@fedora sandbox-print_chars]$ uname -a
Linux fedora.laptop 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.i686.PAE #1 SMP Wed Nov 23 13:39:51 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[mehoggan@fedora sandbox-print_chars]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Next the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

void main()
{
    char *str = "Hello World";
    while(*(str) != '\0') {
        //printf("%c", *(str++));
        //syscall(__NR_write, 1, *(str++), 1);
        __asm__( "movl %0, %%ecx" :"=c" (str));
        __asm__( "movl $0X4, %eax" );
        __asm__( "movl $0X1, %ebx" );
        __asm__( "movl $0X1, %edx" );
        __asm__( "int $0X80" );
        str++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Compiled with the following makefile:

```
all: sandbox_c

sandbox_c: sandbox.c
        gcc -Wall -o sandbox_c ./sandbox.c
        gcc -S -Wall -o sandbox_c.asm ./sandbox.c
```

Things compile just fine, I just cant get the syntax right to get the thing to work. Your corrections are greatly appreciated, but if you could also point me to how you obtained the solution that would be great. I am trying to get better at using the man pages etc.

---

**ADDITION**
Running the executable through gdb I can see that ecx is not being pointed at the right address:

```
[mehoggan@fedora sandbox-print_chars]$ gdb ./sandbox_c
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.2-52.fc14)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/mehoggan/Code/Assembly/sandbox/sandbox-print_chars/sandbox_c...done.
(gdb) break sandbox.c:8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483a2: file ./sandbox.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mehoggan/Code/Assembly/sandbox/sandbox-print_chars/sandbox_c 

Breakpoint 1, main () at ./sandbox.c:8
8       while(*(str) != '\0') {
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.13-2.i686
(gdb) step
11          __asm__( "movl %0, %%ecx" :"=c" (str));
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x48 72
ecx            0x34092fad   873017261
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0x567ff4 5668852
esp            0xbffff2a4   0xbffff2a4
ebp            0xbffff2b8   0xbffff2b8
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483a4    0x80483a4 <main+16>
eflags         0x200206 [ PF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
(gdb) step
12          __asm__( "movl $0X4, %eax" );
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x48 72
ecx            0x34092fad   873017261
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0x34092fad   873017261
esp            0xbffff2a4   0xbffff2a4
ebp            0xbffff2b8   0xbffff2b8
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483ab    0x80483ab <main+23>
eflags         0x200206 [ PF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
(gdb) step
13          __asm__( "movl $0X1, %ebx" );
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x4  4
ecx            0x34092fad   873017261
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0x34092fad   873017261
esp            0xbffff2a4   0xbffff2a4
ebp            0xbffff2b8   0xbffff2b8
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483b0    0x80483b0 <main+28>
eflags         0x200206 [ PF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
(gdb) step
14          __asm__( "movl $0X1, %edx" );
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x4  4
ecx            0x34092fad   873017261
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0x1  1
esp            0xbffff2a4   0xbffff2a4
ebp            0xbffff2b8   0xbffff2b8
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483b5    0x80483b5 <main+33>
eflags         0x200206 [ PF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
(gdb) step
15          __asm__( "int $0X80" );
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x4  4
ecx            0x34092fad   873017261
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0x1  1
esp            0xbffff2a4   0xbffff2a4
ebp            0xbffff2b8   0xbffff2b8
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483ba    0x80483ba <main+38>
eflags         0x200206 [ PF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
(gdb) step
16          str++;
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xfffffff2   -14
ecx            0x34092fad   873017261
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0x1  1
esp            0xbffff2a4   0xbffff2a4
ebp            0xbffff2b8   0xbffff2b8
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483bc    0x80483bc <main+40>
eflags         0x200206 [ PF IF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

Comment: Please never do do this in production code unless you *really* want to limit your program to x86 targets. Not everybody does syscalls the same way, and they certainly don't use the same instructions to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
__asm__ volatile ( "movl $0X4, %eax
                    movl $0X1, %ebx
                    movl $0X1, %edx
                    int $0X80"
                   : /* outputs:  */ /* none */
                   : /* inputs:   */ "c" (str)
                   : /* clobbers: */ "eax", "ebx", "edx");
```

I've not tested it, but the syntax looks right. You might need to add some more "clobbers" if the syscall overwrites anything else - check the documentation.

Breaking it down:

- There's no need to move `%0` to `%ecx` because the `"c"` constraint already did that.
- `str` is an input, but you had it as an output.
- `volatile` tells the compiler not to remove it - it has no output so the compiler might think it can.
- You need to tell the compiler what registers are 'clobbered' by the code. I've added the obvious ones, but the system call might clobber more?
- You need to put them in all one asm or the compiler might think it can move them around.

Comment: Beat me to it ;-) Correct on all these points, unless you use a _single_ `asm()` block (i.e. multiple lines of assembler instructions within _one_ `asm`) and/or declare the block volatile, gcc _will_ "optimize" your assembly, and not necessarily in the way one expects..

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth, calling "int 0x80" *is* making a system call.

You're just not using "printf", or using the standard C library wrappers for Linux syscalls.

And there's nothing wrong with that :)

Anyway, here's a complete example illustrating EXACTLY what you're after:

http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html

'Hope that helps ... and have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already have a pure assembly program that prints hello world. I am trying to figure out how to access a char* in a C program through inline assembly.